# Estimate Shipping On Cart Display Including Tax In Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, tax

I was wondering if anybody knows how to show the "Estimate Shipping" on the /checkout/cart page including tax?

I don't believe this can be achieved with a configuration setting and was wondering if anybody else has come across this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to do this using configuration either.

I achieved this by rewriting `Magento_Checkout/web/template/cart/shipping-rates.html` and modifying the template to output:

```
<!-- ko text: $parents[1].getFormattedPrice(price_incl_tax) --><!-- /ko -->
```

instead of:

```
<!-- ko text: $parents[1].getFormattedPrice(amount) --><!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: With this solution I sometimes have a 1 cent difference between this value and the one displayed in my shipping subtotal.